Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH won't let me login ubuntu 24.04
I am trying to install a software GrADS in Ubuntu 24.04. I want to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in .profile.
export DIR=/usr/local/SOFT

export PATH=$PATH:$DIR/grads/grads-2.2.1/bin

export GADDIR=$DIR/grads/grads-2.2.1/lib/data2

export GASCRP=$DIR/grads/grads-2.2.1/lib

export GAUDPT=$DIR/grads/grads-2.2.1/lib/udpt

#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DIR/grads/supplibs/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Whenever I uncomment the last line, I cannot login to my system. I give the correct password and there is an endless login loop. When I export this from the terminal, it works fine. What can be the error?
Merry Christmas!

Perhaps there is a shared library in $DIR/grads/supplibs/lib that conflicts with a system library? In any case, it's usually better practice to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH only for the specific program(s) that require it - via wrapper scripts or aliases for example.

Yes, the problem was only in that directory. It worked with a wrapper script. Since I have to use the program very often is there any way to identify and resolve the conflict?

Check journalctl to see what errors appear when the login loop happens. You can use the "since" option to give the output since a certain date or time. For example, to give all output since December 24th, 2024: journalctl -S 2024-12-24 See here for more info on date or time formats accepted by journactl.

@ShreyaBhowmick TBH I don't really see the value in trying to resolve the conflict - you can call the wrapper script by the same name as the original program and place it somewhere early in your PATH (e.g. /usr/local/bin or $HOME/bin)

@steeldriver /Putting the wrapper with same executable name grads in $HOME/bin gives the error        bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
/home/shreya/bin/grads: line 7: /home/shreya/bin/grads: Argument list too long

@mchid I did try it but I am a novice to understand that error

@ShreyaBhowmick hard to advise without seeing your script ... make sure it refers to the original grads by its absolute path (otherwise it will just keep calling itself)

@steeldriver This is my script #!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/SOFT/grads/supplibs/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
grads "$@"  The excecutable is grads with options -l or -n

@steeldriver Yes you are right I was calling the script itself. Gave the path of the original executable and now its working! Thank you.
